# Select Pairs in a List

Tags: list-manipulation

We have a list as

```
list = {{h, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}}, {k, {{1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {2, 
 2, 1}, {2, 1}}}, {r, {{1, 1, 2}, {3, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 4}, {2, 1, 
 5}}}};
```

We wish to have another list containing just pairs:

```
list = {{h, { {1, 3}, {1, 4}}}, {k, {{1, 3}, {2, 1}}}, {r, { {3, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 4}}}};
```

How can we use `Pick` or `Select` or other functions for this aim?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select` can be used to identify pairs in sub-lists, such as

```
Select[list[[1, 2]], Length@# == 2 &]

(* {{1, 3}, {1, 4}} *)
```

Then, use `Map` to apply `Select` to every sub-list:

```
{First@#, Select[Last@#, Length@# == 2 &]} & /@ list

(* {{h, {{1, 3}, {1, 4}}}, {k, {{1, 3}, {2, 1}}}, {r, {{3, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 4}}}} *)
```

Comment: I could understand. it is amazing solution. Without using additional IF condition which was in my decesion

Answer (score 13):

I think you'll find the simple

```
DeleteCases[list, {_, _, __}, {3}]
```

to be a bit more efficient...

Comment: simple and efficient...+1 winner for me:)

Answer (score 7):

Using `ReplaceAll` (`/.`)

```
list /.  {_Integer, _Integer, __} :> Nothing
```

One needs to carefully specify the replacement rules however, try for example

```
list /.  {_, _, __} :> Nothing
(* Nothing *)
```

Rule replacement is actually quite efficient (relatively speaking) in this case, compare the above to @ciao's answer:

```
testList = Join[Apply[Sequence]@Table[list, 200000]]

(res1 = testList /.  {_Integer, _Integer, __} :> Nothing); // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.55462, Null} *)
(res2 = DeleteCases[testList, {_, _, __}, {3}]); // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.769297, Null} *)
res1 == res2
(* True *)
```

For a solution based on rule replacement a factor of ~3 worse than the (supposedly) fastest method isn't half bad.

Comment: *One needs to carefully specify the replacement rules...* well how about `Replace[list, {_, _, __} :> Nothing, {3}]`?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP that one works as well but I though it less general (but maybe safer to use) in case of more deeply nested lists

Answer (score 7):

Using `Apply`

```
f[x_, y_] := {x, y};
f[___] := Nothing;
Apply[f, list, {3}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Pattern Matching:

```
xss = {{h, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}}, {k, {{1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {2, 
 2, 1}, {2, 1}}}, {r, {{1, 1, 2}, {3, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 4}, {2, 1, 
 5}}}}
xss //. {xs___, {_Integer, _Integer, __}, ys___} -> {xs, ys}
```

Test (Special Case, 200000 copies of xss):

```
xss = {{h, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}}, {k, {{1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {2, 
     2, 1}, {2, 1}}}, {r, {{1, 1, 2}, {3, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 4}, {2, 1, 
     5}}}}
testList = Join[Apply[Sequence]@Table[xss, 200000]]
f[xss_] := f[xss] = 
  xss //. {xs___, {_Integer, _Integer, __}, ys___} -> {xs, ys}
AbsoluteTiming[testList // Map[f] ]
```

[image]

Comment: Using `ReplaceRepeated` this way is very inefficient.

Comment: The execution time is 0.000057 seconds.    {0.000057, {{h, {{1, 3}, {1, 4}}}, {k, {{1, 3}, {2, 1}}}, {r, {{3, 
     4}, {2, 1}, {2, 4}}}}}

Comment: try the same with a longer list e.g. a form of `testlist` from my answer (maybe with 1000 copies of the original list)

Comment: @Sascha, It takes 0.194612 seconds to process 200000 copies of the original list.

Comment: Memoization is cheating ;-). You are memoizing just three inputs, this is not a representative test.

Comment: What I meant was that using something like `testlist //. {xs___, {_Integer, _Integer, __}, ys___} -> {xs, ys} ` is very inefficient since `ReplaceRepeated` checks every part of the list at every run an thus wastes a lot of time checking parts of the expression that were already processed.

Comment: @Sascha precisely. But `Map[# //. {xs___, {_Integer, _Integer, __}, ys___} :> {xs, ys} &, 
   testList, {2}]` is okay-ish.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Fair enough, I have just indicated that it's a special case.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Imho using `Map` makes this solution more convoluted than necessary and still does not address the issues of using `ReplaceRepeated` in this fashion i.e. the inner lists could be of vastly different lengths and thus one could end up mapping the repeated replacement onto an enormous inner list.

Comment: @Sascha It depends on the inputs, if an input is a complex big data set but not a 20000 copies of the same data, I will adjust my algorithm. :)

Answer (score 5):

An example with [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html):

```
MapAt[Cases[#, _?(Length@# == 2 &)] &, list, {All, 2}]
```

yielding:

```
(* {{h, {{1, 3}, {1, 4}}}, {k, {{1, 3}, {2, 1}}}, {r, {{3, 4}, {2, 
    1}, {2, 4}}}}*)
```